# Read value from backed table once in bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to read value from table once modal show with form. 
I'm not able to get value from table behind modal. is there any specific rules?

What am I doing wrong? Would like to read value of backed table fields and wants to use for calculation of the modal fields.

please check example here -
[Sample Code](https://jsfiddle.net/1s9u629w/50/)

```
/*doesn't read value of rollno from table when modal input box on change*/
$('#frm_name').change(function() {
  var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
  var rowID = $row.attr('class').split('_')[1];
  var rollno = $row.find('.td_rollno').text();
  alert(rollno);
});
```

HTML

```
<table class="table table-responsive">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>NAME</th>
      <th>ROLL NUMBER</th>
      <th>CONTACT NO</th>
      <th>ADDRESS</th>
      <th>EDIT</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="trID_1">
      <td class="td_name">Name Row1</td>
      <td class="td_rollno">12345</td>
      <td class="td_contact">Mickey Mouse</td>
      <td class="td_address">123 Mouse Lane</td>
      <td>
        <button class='td_btn btn btn-link btn-custom dis'>EDIT</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="trID_2">
      <td class="td_name">Name Row2</td>
      <td class="td_rollno">22222</td>
      <td class="td_contact">Wiley Coyote</td>
      <td class="td_address">RR3 Road Runner Lane</td>
      <td>
        <button class='td_btn btn btn-link btn-custom dis'>EDIT</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="trID_3">
      <td class="td_name">Name Row3</td>
      <td class="td_rollno">33333</td>
      <td class="td_contact">Pepe LePew</td>
      <td class="td_address">88 Stink Street</td>
      <td>
        <button class='td_btn btn btn-link btn-custom dis'>EDIT</button>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">EDIT RECORD</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <form id="updateValues" action="update.php" method="POST" class="form">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">NAME</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="frm_name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="contact">CONTACT</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="contact" id="frm_contact">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="address">ADDRESS</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="address" id="frm_address"></textarea>
          </div>
          <input type="hidden" name="frm_id">
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-custom" value="Save changes">
        </form>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <div id="results"></div>
      </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Reading values from `tr` to the modal inputs is **already** working. What is the purpose of this `change` event handler? `#frm_name` input doesn't have any `tr` parents.

Comment: If you try in jsfiddle , once i'm in modal , I would like to change value of input address with name field in table but it doesn't read value from table anymore once I'm in modal... THAT IS THE PROBLEM..

Comment: This is just an example sample code... in reality I have reason behind doing this... would like to have table row value for calculation of the modal fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your markup suggests trying to update a record with a modal form that posts to update.php. Separately, you have a jQuery function that looks like an attempt to update the table contents with the modal inputs.

If I understand you correctly, you will want to instead read the docs for your particular PHP framework for how to:

- submit forms via AJAX
- handle successful update with a script that will update the DOM accordingly

Comment: thank you for your time, Only issue I have here is I'm not able to read value of rollno from table once I try to get value of rollno on change of input box of modal... any tricks or am i doing something wrong .?

Comment: The issue is scope. You can add your vars to a higher scope, and have both of your functions inherit that scope and write over the vars as needed.
  
See demo-- edit name and click away from name to trigger change event: https://jsfiddle.net/1s9u629w/51/

Comment: @got it... that was i was looking for.. :)

Comment: Still wondering.. why doesn't it read directly from modal call rather than creating globe variables.. ? any specific rules.?